# Suitable choice for the activation function of a neural network

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network

[image]

[image]

I didn't understand exactly the question about point 2. Is it a good way to solve the task applying the same activation function for all the layers or could it be a better solution to apply different activation functions for different layers ? Is it a good choice to apply the sigmoid function ? Could it be a good choice to use the Sigmoid function for the intermediate layers ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try many different variations of architecture of your ANN. Here is no some rule to pick architecture optimally it is an empirical case. Take look this links:

1. [link1](https://www.quora.com/How-should-I-choose-a-proper-activation-function-for-the-neural-network)
2. [link2](https://medium.com/the-theory-of-everything/understanding-activation-functions-in-neural-networks-9491262884e0)

Here is a snippet from this article:

> Now, which activation functions to use. Does that mean we just use
>   ReLu for everything we do? Or sigmoid or tanh? Well, yes and no. When
>   you know the function you are trying to approximate has certain
>   characteristics, you can choose an activation function which will
>   approximate the function faster leading to faster training process.
>   For example, a sigmoid works well for a classifier ( see the graph of
>   sigmoid, doesn’t it show the properties of an ideal classifier? )
>   because approximating a classifier function as combinations of sigmoid
>   is easier than maybe ReLu, for example. Which will lead to faster
>   training process and convergence. You can use your own custom
>   functions too!. If you don’t know the nature of the function you are
>   trying to learn, then maybe i would suggest start with ReLu, and then
>   work backwards. ReLu works most of the time as a general approximator!

Anyway I would pick Sigmoid function in hidden layer and Linear in output layer

Comment: Thanks for the help , but may I ask you why do you choose the Sigmoid function in hidden layer if in the article it says that sigmoid is a good idea for a classifier while my exercise is not a classification problem ?

Comment: because I have experience in using Sigmoid function in non classification problems, actually in function approximation as your problem is. You will get desired result in any case if you use any functions discussed in this articles, but you should pick better one for your actual problem. I said that just because I have used Sigmoid in similar problem

Comment: Ok I understood , just to simplify , am I right if I say that I can use the sigmoid function (0,1) to understand which units are relevant and which no ? And then get the output with the help of the linear function ?

Comment: I don't understand well but I'll try to explain my opinion about solving your problem. You take three-layered network (some people calls it two layered), first layer is inputs (your x-es), then hidden layer with sigmoid activation functions and then linear outputs. Then you should train your network where train samples are your t-s